# Open, big time-series dataset (ideally web traffic)

Tags: data-request, time-series, internet

I'm working on a project for automatically identifying and sorting web analytics incidents.

As part of testing of the software, I'm looking for time-series dataset (ideally >100K rows) with **daily** data broken down by some **well-defined dimensions** (e.g. country, marketing channel etc). I'd be better if the dataset contained more than just one metric (e.g. visits and orders).

Does anyone of you know about any such public dataset?

Comment: It seems the documentation ( A Week in the Life of a Browse) link is not working.
Do you know what the ``Events'' mean?, i.e. what is an event ?

Comment: See the alternative download site in the answer below

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it fits your criteria, but consider the **[A Week in the Life of a Browser](https://testpilot.mozillalabs.com/testcases/a-week-life-2/aggregated-data.html)** data set, which combines browsing history with survey data.

> Test duration: 7 days
>
> Test type: Global
>
> Firefox versions covered: Fx 3.5 and Fx 3.6, Fx4 Beta
>
> Data submission: 527,817 test sets submitted in November 2010.

Three Tables:

1. Table Name: 'users'

   - Main table of users and the metadata associated with each user.
2. Table Name: 'events'

   - Main table of users and recorded events.
3. Table name: 'survey'

   - Table of users and associated Beta Background Survey answers.

Data formats are either CSV or SQL dump.

Data is licensed by [Creative Commons Attribution 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/).

---

**UPDATE**: [Alternative download site](http://datahub.io/dataset/a-week-in-the-life-of-a-browser-version-2)

Comment: Thanks @philshem but there seems to be a problem with the links on the website, so I cannot download them.

Comment: @Stergios We have tracked down this dataset and hosted it. Does it work for you?

Comment: OK I downloaded the files. Thanks a lot, I appreciate it!!

Answer (score 2):

I publish the [Google Play Store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Play#Google_Play_Store) statistics of one of my apps:

http://datahub.io/dataset/google-play-statistics/

See for instance the [installs per device type](http://datahub.io/dataset/google-play-statistics/resource/4300d529-4e83-46ea-b19b-b5510966ddd0). It is fragmented by day, with metrics such as installs/uninstalls/upgrades.

It is less than 100K rows, though, as data is pre-aggregated.

Comment: Thanks @Nicolas Raoul! I think it's very close to what I need. I'll definitely check it!!

Comment: Do you think it would be possible to have such a dataset with multiple dimensions (e.g. installs per country, device type, app version etc)??

Comment: @Stergios: Installs per country, per device type, per app version, and many more dimensions, are already available in my dataset, you just have to correlate the various CSV files by date :-)

Comment: Nicolas, I don't see how I can get, for instance, installs from DE, from '10_or_more_inch_tablets' on 2015-01-12. Is there such a dataset available?

Comment: @Stergios: Installs from DE on 2015-01-12 are available in the `country-installs.csv` file. Installs on '10_or_more_inch_tablets' on 2015-01-12 are available in the `device_class_installs.csv` file. But unfortunately, installs per country per device class per day data is not available.