# Where I can find a repository of software usage/execution logs (traces)?

Tags: data-request, software

I'm looking for recorded information about a program's execution. I'm not interested in logging information, but in software tracing data.

The more information about software internal it contains the merrier it is.

Following is a trace example:

```
INFO: Call from main.RunFile line 206 to main.RunFile.main
Mar 31, 2011 2:52:53 PM aspects.Trace ajc$before$aspects_Trace$1$b314f86e
INFO: Call from main.RunFile line 186 to main.RunFile.runList
Mar 31, 2011 2:52:53 PM main.RunFile main
INFO: Starting clustering of 0 files
Mar 31, 2011 2:52:53 PM aspects.Trace ajc$before$aspects_Trace$1$b314f86e
INFO: Call from main.ExperimentRunner line 59 to main.ExperimentRunner.runExperiments
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider using the EVENT table from the Mozilla Labs ["Day in the Life of a Browser](https://testpilot.mozillalabs.com/testcases/a-week-life-2/aggregated-data.html)" dataset.

[image]

<s>Unfortunately the download links are inactive. But this dataset has come up on [another question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/4633/1511) and hopefully Mozilla will fix it soon.</s>

License is Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 United States.

**UPDATE**: data is now hosted [here](http://datahub.io/dataset/a-week-in-the-life-of-a-browser-version-2)