# Find a missing dataset: "A Week in the life of a browser - Version 2" from Mozilla Labs

Tags: data-request, internet

It's come up as an answer for two questions:

1. [Open, big time-series dataset (ideally web traffic)](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/4633/1511)
2. [Where I can find a repository of software usage/execution logs (traces)?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/4952/1511)

Here is the main page: [A Week in the Life of a Browser - Version 2: Aggregated Data Samples](https://testpilot.mozillalabs.com/testcases/a-week-life-2/aggregated-data.html)

But the download links for the 3 data files is dead. For example:

```
https://testpilot.mozillalabs.com/testcases/a-week-life-2/witl_small.tar.gz
```

The relevant HTML source for the page can be found in this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/mozilla/testpilotweb/blob/master/testcases/a-week-life-2/aggregated-data.html)

```
<table class="callout">
    <tr>
        <td><span class="headers">Filename</span>
        </td>
        <td><span class="headers">Download Size</span>
        </td>
        <td><span class="headers">Num. of Tables</span>
        </td>
        <td><span class="headers">Num. of Users</span>
        </td>
        <td><span class="headers">Description</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="witl.db.gz">witl.db.gz</a>
        </td>
        <td>1.1 GB</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>About 27,000</td>
        <td>Gzipped SQL dump of all three tables</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="witl_large.tar.gz">witl_large.tar.gz</a>
        </td>
        <td>469 MB</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>About 27,000</td>
        <td>Gzipped Tar archive of three CSV files, one for each table</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="witl_small.tar.gz">witl_small.tar.gz</a>
        </td>
        <td>7.4 MB</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>About 27,000, 387 w/ event data</td>
        <td>Gzipped Tar archive of three CSV files, one for each table</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In this case, the links to the download files point to the same folder, which is [empty otherwise](https://github.com/mozilla/testpilotweb/tree/master/testcases/a-week-life-2).

**Who can find these data sets?** (so we can properly host them)

One hint: find [this guy](http://theuforce.blogspot.ch/2010/12/mozilla-open-data-visualization.html) and see if he still has a copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just snagged it off the [wayback machine](http://archive.org/web/) here:

```
http://web.archive.org/web/20110711102216/https://testpilot.mozillalabs.com/testcases/a-week-life-2/witl_small.tar.gz
```

but more files can be found here by searching for '.tar.gz' or '.db.gz'

```
http://web.archive.org/web/*/https://testpilot.mozillalabs.com/testcases/*
```

---

[**Download the data**](http://datahub.io/dataset/a-week-in-the-life-of-a-browser-version-2)

---

Download links from Wayback Machine:

- [witl.db.gz](http://web.archive.org/web/20110711095832/https://testpilot.mozillalabs.com/testcases/a-week-life-2/witl.db.gz) (1.1 GB, SQLite 3.x database)
- [witl_large.tar.gz](http://web.archive.org/web/20110817232850/https://testpilot.mozillalabs.com/testcases/a-week-life-2/witl_large.tar.gz) (469 MB, CSV files)
- [witl_small.tar.gz](http://web.archive.org/web/20110817232850/https://testpilot.mozillalabs.com/testcases/a-week-life-2/witl_small.tar.gz) (7.4 MB, CSV files)

---

Details:

[image]

Comment: Great find. Where should we re-host them?

Comment: p.s. I fixed the links. The * in the URL was making the text italic.

Comment: idk @philshem i was just thinking about that. i could put it on datahub, but my account is for Open Hampton Roads Data, i could make a free standing github repo, but it'll be linked to my account....can you make a datahub.io account for Open Data SE - probably better taking up on meta